# NAs introduced by coercion in fuzzy cmeans

Tags: r

Error in [`e1071::cmeans`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-9/topics/cmeans):

```
data <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=T)
View(data)
data.features = data
View(dataku.features)
data.features$SNAMA.SMA <-NULL
View(data.features)
library(e1071)
result <- cmeans(data.features,3,20,verbose=TRUE,method="cmeans",m=2)
result
plot(data[c("NAMA.SMA","SISWA","GURU","KARYAWAN","PEKERJA","PENGAWAS")], col=result$cluster)
```

When I run the line `result <- cmeans(data.features,3,20,verbose=TRUE,method="cmeans",m=2)`
I get the following error (and warnings):

> Error in cmeans(data.features, 3, 20, verbose = TRUE, method = "cmeans",  :
> NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In cmeans(data.features, 3, 20, verbose = TRUE, method = "cmeans",  :
> NAs introduced by coercion
> 2: In cmeans(data.features, 3, 20, verbose = TRUE, method = "cmeans",  :
> NAs introduced by coercion

What am I doing wrong?

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/139LrBdq4jQVVNkA2akZdKxOkUBhy2AtG/view)

Comment: please provide data, use `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: @Pax Alrighty, just a sec

Comment: @Pax i cant attach the data. But this is the link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/139LrBdq4jQVVNkA2akZdKxOkUBhy2AtG/view?usp=sharing